# European DIN Specification bathroom lock standard door preperation, has a 60mm offset

Tags: doors, mortise

I'm not able to find the standard door preparation for a European specification DIN bathroom latch.  The kind with a 60mm offset.

This one specifically, https://www.gjohns.co.uk/din-style-bathroom-mortice-lock-60mm-backset-78mm-centres-satin-stainless-steel.html

I have questions like, what size hole should be drilled.  Are the knobs set apart a specified distance?  Or is only the case size specified?

Answer (score 1):

the hole must be big enough for the axles, the largest is 8mm square so an 11mm round hole will do if it's correctly located.  the knobs are 78mm apart vertically

As per the drawing on that web site:
[image]